# AS3 efficient way to make a disabled state

Tags: actionscript-3

So, I have a number of UI classes I have created, which all extend another class `ControlBase`.
The `ControlBase` class contains a getter and setter for an `enabled` property.

What I am aiming to achieve is that whenever a UI element, let's say a `Button` class, is disabled, all mouse events stop.

I am awake of `mouseEnabled` however, I sill want it to block any elements behind it, if that makes sense. (So if I have a button on top of another button, the bottom button doesn't get activated when top button is disabled)

Currently, I have achieved this, but it feels like it may be rather inefficient. The way I am achieving it is by putting this code in the `ControlBase` class constructor:

```
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkMouseEvent, false, int.MAX_VALUE, true);
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, checkMouseEvent, false, int.MAX_VALUE, true);
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, checkMouseEvent, false, int.MAX_VALUE, true);
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, checkMouseEvent, false, int.MAX_VALUE, true);
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, checkMouseEvent, false, int.MAX_VALUE, true);
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, checkMouseEvent, false, int.MAX_VALUE, true);
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, checkMouseEvent, false, int.MAX_VALUE, true);
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, checkMouseEvent, false, int.MAX_VALUE, true);
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, checkMouseEvent, false, int.MAX_VALUE, true);
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, checkMouseEvent, false, int.MAX_VALUE, true);
    this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeyboardEvent, false, int.MAX_VALUE, true);
    this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeyboardEvent, false, int.MAX_VALUE, true);
```

And then also putting:

```
private function checkMouseEvent(e:MouseEvent):void {
            if (!enabled) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        }
private function checkKeyboardEvent(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if (!enabled) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        }
```

in the same class. So these events fire before any other event (because they have the maximum allowed priority) and then stop the propagation of the event if the control is disabled.

I do feel it may be inefficient though because of the large number of events that are now being listened for. Will this pose a problem when there are a large number of UI elements being used?
If so, does anyone have any ideas for a more memory efficient system?

Thanks, Will

*Edit:* Maybe I should override the `addEventListener` method on the `ControlBase` class with somethin along the lines of:

```
override public function addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean=false, priority:int=0, useWeakReference:Boolean=false):void {
super.addEventListener(type, function(e:Event) {
if (enabled) listener(e);
}, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);
}
```

Or is this not a good way of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have thought something more along the lines of a background layer that your buttons are on would prevent MouseEvents triggering below.

> Maybe I should override the addEventListener method on the ControlBase
>   class

This would not stop events being triggered as it only stops the event listener being added, but once added they would still trigger regardless of whether enabled.

Comment: Surely though, if I override the addEventListener function to wrap any added functions with an enabled check before adding them that would work? Although, I guess by making new anonymous functions it will break the removrEventListener function.

Comment: @WillBennion if when the button is first initialized, it is enabled, the events will always work, if it was disabled it will always be disabled, since the check is at the point of adding the event listener rather than at the point when events are thrown